# How to set timezone for calendar in magento?

Tags: javascript, magento, calendar

I am new to Magento and have no clue how to solve this,please help.
Magento by default uses UTC timezone but i want my calendar widgit to be in est timezone. I changed the timezone to EST form admin section under locale options (system->configuration->general->locale options) but still my calendar is using UTC time. Do we have to set it somewhere else?

Comment: Did you... clear the cache after changing?

Comment: Yes i did.. but still it was not working..